# How to make a horizontally scrolling panel or carousel?

Tags: html, css, carousel

I'm looking for something similar like this on steam (horizontal scrolling, if mouse hover it stops):

**Just like** [this](http://store.steampowered.com/)

Comment: it's called a carousel http://getbootstrap.com/examples/carousel/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The feature is called a [carousel](http://www.w3.org/WAI/tutorials/carousels/) and you can find many samples on the Internet. ([here](https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/demos/basic.html) and [here](https://css-tricks.com/creating-responsive-touch-friendly-carousels-with-flickity/))

> Carousels, commonly also referred to as “slide shows” or “sliders”, display a series of content items one at a time; for example, a series of news headlines. Carousels often use animations to move from slide to slide which can be distracting for some users. They may also move so fast automatically that their content is hard or impossible to grasp, which is why every carousel should have a function to pause the animation.